# Twig, in array function

Tags: arrays, twig

I want to do tricky thing, something like in array function in PHP.
For example, my array:

```
0 => business
1 => person
2 => contact
```

Now I want to check if in my array exist value for example 'business'. In this case exist so it should be true, for example for 'busi' or 'aaa' it should be false. Is there any easy way to do it ?

This doesn't work properly for me:

```
{% if 'aaa' in types|keys %}
```

It's always true...

Answer (score 0):

Can you just check with the [defined](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tests/defined.html)?

To check for key

```
 {% if types['aaa'] is defined %}
```

To check for value

```
{% if ('aaa' in types) %}
```

Comment: It will check key, not value.

Comment: right you are, I read your code more than your text :). Should work if you just remove the | keys part from your code - it just makes the if to check the keys, not values.

Comment: I will check it in the evening and I let you now is it working, for now I made yesterday simple loop but for in my opinion it's shitty option so I want to make something better :P